# Is this possible to disable some features in npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to execute a user input js to my node js server for execution. But I am afraid that the user may do something bad, for example, remove all the files in my server or write a lots of files in my server.

In order to avoid this, I would like to disable all the read/write operation in that node js server. Is this possible to do so? If yes, please advise.

Comment: Why not sanitize input first?

Comment: so, you want to disable some features of node? what does NPM have to do with that?

Comment: Why not execute this script in a separate process under a user with limited access? This way you don't need to worry about bad things happening -> the worst thing that will happen is that if the user tries to execute some bad things, his script will not work.

Answer (score 0):

To run that script use either:

- containers
- zones
- jails
- VMs

depending on what your OS supports.

This is basically what CI services like Travis do. They run my untrusted code, they even let me use npm to install modules, and then they destroy the container and no harm is done. It's like every time I would get a new freshly reinstalled OS.

Never run any untrusted code, even as an unprivileged user.

For possible solutions to your problem see:

- https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html
- https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Zones
- https://www.docker.com/
- https://www.vagrantup.com/
- https://linuxcontainers.org/
- https://illumos.org/man/5/zones
- http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page
- https://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/7.1+Zones
- http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=chroot